# initdb.bin: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables

Tags: odoo, bitnami

When I tried to install **bitnami odoo 9** in my ubuntu system via terminal, I got the following error message.

How to solve this issue?

```
initdb.bin: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The issue solved when i used the following commands

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

For Unix you have to be

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I'm using a Norwegian Mac, I don't know if a different solution is required

Comment: I had to add `export` keyword - `export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"` and `export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"`

Answer (score 7):

On the docker image I was using every single locale was commented out in the /etc/locale.gen file. Meaning no locale was setup, which was causing this error.

Because I was scripting the build I ran the following two commands to fix the problem (you may want to manually edit /etc/locale.gen, if you want to avoid my nuclear option of overwriting the whole file)

```
echo en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 > /etc/locale.gen
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) I had to set all these.

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

The full doc is [here](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Perl_warning_Setting_locale_failed_in_Debian).

Answer (score 1):

For me it is part of using ssh

So edit sshd config file

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and change LANG part it to this:

```
AcceptEnv LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

then restart ssh and reconnect

```
sudo service sshd restart
```