# PostgreSQL's `initdb` fails with "invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables"

Tags: postgresql, locale

Already found a solution for this ([see answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50746213/1498178)), but I am not sure that it is the appropriate one; plus this may help someone else too.

---

Tried to set up PostgreSQL by following the documentation ([18.2 Creating a Database Cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/creating-cluster.html)), but got the following error on Ubuntu 18.04 (kernel: 4.15.0-22-generic):

```
$ initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
  (...)
initdb: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables
```

Found a couple answers on Stackoverflow ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956994/initdb-bin-invalid-locale-settings-check-lang-and-lc-environment-variables), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337557/badvalue-invalid-or-no-user-locale-set-please-ensure-lang-and-or-lc-environme)) that were relevant, but these did not resolve the issue and the [one on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/491237/postgresql-9-2-invalid-locale-name-on-ubuntu-12-04) suggested to restart the service, but PostgreSQL wasn't even running.

Tried passing the locale explicitly in every variation that I found on the system, but these failed too,

```
 3617  2018/06/07-08:36 initdb -D ~/Downloads/ --locale=en_US.utf8
 3618  2018/06/07-08:36 initdb -D ~/Downloads/ --locale=en_US.UTF8
 3621  2018/06/07-08:37 initdb -D ~/Downloads/ --locale=en_US.UTF-8
 3622  2018/06/07-08:37 initdb -D ~/Downloads/ --locale="en_US.UTF-8"
 3623  2018/06/07-08:37 initdb -D ~/Downloads/ --locale="en_US.utf8"
 3645  2018/06/07-09:24 initdb -D ~/Downloads/ --locale="en_US.utf8"
```

with

```
initdb: invalid locale name <the_option_value_above>
```

There was [an Arch Linux forum discussion about this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=203629), but there were no solution.

---

2018/06/07 1214 UPDATE

I linked answers above, but perhaps wasn't explicit enough: I did look at `locale -a` and `locale` (not listing the former's output because I installed ALL of them in my attempts below):

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

What have been tried, but did not work (and terminal has been restarted for every iteration):

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/454260/how-to-solve-locale-problem

  Selected and configured ALL locales.

  ```
  $ sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

  $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales.
  ```
- https://github.com/singularityware/singularity/issues/11

  neither

  ```
  echo "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/environment
  echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen
  echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/locale.conf
  locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
  ```

  nor

  ```
  sudo apt clean
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt upgrade
  sudo apt-get install -y locales language-pack-fi language-pack-en
  export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
  export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
  sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
  ```
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue/229512#229512
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/114759/warning-setlocale-lc-all-cannot-change-locale

  (Basically variations of the github link above, tried it anyway.)

TODO:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294845/bash-warning-setlocale-lc-all-cannot-change-locale-en-us-utf-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this thread](http://misc.openbsd.narkive.com/2f3pxUH0/postgresql-9-4-initdb-invalid-locale-settings):

```
initdb -D <your_data_location> --no-locale --encoding=UTF8
```

where

```
  --locale=LOCALE       set default locale for new databases
  --no-locale           equivalent to --locale=C
```

There are caveats (see warning below), but an all-utf8 database can be created using `template0` (see [21.3. Template Databases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html)).

From the client (`psql`):

```
postgres=# create database test LC_COLLATE "en_US.UTF-8" LC_CTYPE "en_US.UTF-8" template template0;
```

Or via `createdb`:

```
createdb --lc-collate="en_US.UTF-8" --lc-ctype="en_US.UTF-8" --template="template0" test2
```

Check:

```
$ psql
psql (10.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C           | C           | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C           | C           | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C           | C           | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 test      | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 test2     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

---

WARNING: **This is probably not the correct solution and the workaround above is just that, a workaround.**

Note the "Collate" and "Ctype" fields below in a database created with the above solution and this may cause issues, because "*The results of comparisons between strings depends on `LC_CTYPE`. In practice, the most visible effect is the sort order*." ([see DBA StackExchange thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94887/what-is-the-impact-of-lc-ctype-on-a-postgresql-database)). This is also confirmed on the PostgreSQL mailing list (see [this thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/A737B7A37273E048B164557ADEF4A58B53A81CA2%40ntex2010i.host.magwien.gv.at) about this issue on a database in production). Probably the easiest way to solve this would be [re-initializing/recreating the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420925/change-database-collation-ctype-in-postgresql).

```
postgres=# \l
                             List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 5):

Although the question does not mention Nix, the original poster linked to this issue from the [Nix discourse site](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-configure-postgresql-declaratively-nixos-and-non-nixos/4063/15) so I believe this is a Nix-related issue.

I ran into this issue when running under Nix shell and found the solution [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/60414) after much searching.  I just had to add `glibcLocales` to my environment.  I.e. either run `nix-shell -p glibcLocales` or add `glibcLocales` to `buildInputs`.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I originally had this issue on NixOS but then on an older Ubuntu as well so it warranted the creation of a general question. I can't try this out right now but really appreciate your efforts - this can be an arduous issue to find a solution for..

Answer (score 4):

You can get a listing of the locales available in Linux with

```bash
locale -a
```

Use one of these.

You have to choose a locale that matches your encoding, for example

```bash
initdb -E UTF8 --locale=en_US.utf8
```

or

```bash
initdb -E LATIN9 --locale=et_EE.iso885915
```

As far as I know, you can install additional locales with

```bash
sudo apt-get install language-pack-XX
```

Comment: This answer set me on a death spiral. Isn't the -U flag used to define the initial superuser? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-initdb.html

Comment: This should probably be `initdb -E UTF8 ...`, not `-U`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check if the locale is enabled in `/etc/locale.gen`. On my fresh install of Arch Linux ARM the following line was commented out:

   ```
   en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
   ```
2. Run `locale-gen` without any arguments. It will list all the uncommented locales as it generates them.
3. Optional: edit `/etc/locale.conf` to set the system locale:

   ```
   echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/locale.conf
   ```

   Restart the system to make all services pick up the new setting.
4. Run your `initdb` command.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was an issue when I tried to upgrade postgres from 9.6 to 15.
**locale** should be replaced with **local-provider** and **icu locale**, e.g.:

```
POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="--locale=nl_NL --encoding=UTF8"
```

->

```
POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="--locale-provider=icu --icu-locale=nl_NL --encoding=UTF8
```